# Listview with image depending on context

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and currently experience with a listview. All my items are displayed correctly but now I would like to add an image out of my drawable folder depending on the content.

```
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_event);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this, eventList,
            R.layout.list_item_event, new String[] { "name", "date" }, 
new int[]  {R.id.name, R.id.date});
lv.setAdapter( adapter );
```

My eventList contains more fields like for example "type" which only havs three different values. Now in case it contains type1 I want that it takes the png image type1 out of the drawable folder (R.drawable). 
Is there anyone so kind and gives me please a hint?

Comment: Try to make your custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial:

http://webdeveloperpadawan.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/android-listview-with-differing-rows.html

In short, inside getView() you need to check the type and set the image based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a Integer array of drawable images as {R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2};
and on the basis of data coming take the respective integer value from array.you have to map like this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in order to include pictures into your list view you will need to have a custom adapter.

In order to do so, create a class that extends Adapter (or in this example ArrayAdapter):

```
public class ParticipantAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Participant> {

private final Context context;
private final List<Participant> values;
private final String urlToProfilePics;

public ParticipantAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<Participant> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = objects;
}

public ParticipantAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = new ArrayList<Participant>();
    // Obtain the external cache directory
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View participantView;
    participantView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.participant_item, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) participantView.findViewById(R.id.participantName);
    textView.setText(getItem(position).getName());
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) participantView.findViewById(R.id.participantImage);

    //you can add varibles to the class that represents your items and use it like so to determine the image displayed
    int someContext = getItem(position).someContextOfTheCurrentItem;
    switch(someContext) {
        case DOG:
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog);
            break;
        case CAT:
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat);
            break;
    }

    //here are some other things you can do on the image based on the context of your item
    if(!getItem(position).someBoolean) {
        imageView.setImageAlpha(80);
        int lightGrey = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_grey);
        textView.setTextColor(lightGrey);
    } else {
        int black = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black);
        textView.setTextColor(black);
    }

    return participantView;
}

public List<Participant> getValues() {
    return this.values;
}
```

Mind the `getView` method. What it does is take a XML file of a layout that includes an image and manipulates it based on the context of each item.

In this example, I have a seperate class called `Participant`, and it contains an integer and a boolean on which I am doing tests in the `getView` method, and based on their values I can change what the returned `View` will represent.

Here is the xml file of the layout I used in this example (it's just a picture and with a text view to its right):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/participantImage"
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionParticipantImage"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/tom_max_width_participant_image"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_placeholder" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/participantName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/tom_small_text_padding"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColorHint="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/tom_participant_item_text_size" />
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for their answers.
Finally I could get managed it as recommended with a new class

```
public class EventAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] string_event;
private final int[] int_event;
private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items;

public EventAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items,
                    String[] string_event, int[] int_event) {
    super(context, items, R.layout.list_item_event, string_event, int_event);

    this.context = context;
    this.string_event = string_event;
    this.int_event = int_event;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_event, null, true);

    System.out.println("Items position: " + items.get(position));
    EventClass currentEvent = new EventClass(items.get(position).get("name").toString(), items.get(position).get("location"), items.get(position).get("date")
                , items.get(position).get("type"), items.get(position).get("theme"),items.get(position).get("link"));

    TextView txtName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(int_event[0]);
    TextView txtDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(int_event[1]);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_type);

    txtName.setText(currentEvent.getEvent_name());
    txtDate.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd MMMM yyyy",currentEvent.getDate()));

    if(currentEvent.getType().equals("triathlon")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.triathlon_70);
    }
    if(currentEvent.getType().equals("run")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_run_70);
    }
    if(currentEvent.getType().equals("cycling")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cycle_70);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

}

I really assumed in first place it would be much easier :)
Thanks again